# Mongoose model resave model attribute (object) as new

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have model "User" with anttribute "requirements", which is object containing many other attributes and means requirements for another level. For example:

```
User: {
    name: "Jack",
    requirements: {
        animals: {
           panda: 1,
           lion: 2
        },
        stock: {
            water: 3
        }
    }
}
```

When user buy animal or bucket of water, I decrement bought item from requirements, so eventually, user has all attributes in requirements equal to zero. When user acomplishes this, he levels up and new requirements object is set representing new requirements for another level:

```
user.requirements = undefined;
// Line A
user.requirements = {
    animals: { fox: 1}
}
user.save();
```

But when I do this, then in database stays requirements from previous requirements object as zero, so instead of object above is this object:

```
User: {
    name: "Jack",
    requirements: {
        animals: {
           panda: 0,
           lion: 0,
           fox: 1
        },
        stock: {
            water: 0
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get rid of requirements with zeroes, but only when I level up, not when I ordinary save model (like User needs 1 panad, User bought 1 panda, it will decrement panda requirement by 1 and save requirements with quantity 0 - that's ok. What isn't OK is when users complete all requirements - set to 0, and load new level requirements - and after loading there are still some 0 in it.

Maybe if I would save model at line A? Bu I think this is not good to save twice - and I would need to result asynchronous nature of saving. Is there any easier or better solution?

ISSUE IN SHORTCUT IN EXAMPLE
I need to buy 1 panda and 1 bucket of water for level up. So I buy 1 panda. Requirements for panda is now 0 - that's ok. Then I buy 1 bucket of water. Now I finished all requirements (they're all 0), so I level up - change requirements to new. After change of requirements, thare must not be any 0, especially not 0 from previous requirements.

Comment: I'm confused about the exact question/issue here. Do you want to completely remove any nested properties in `requirements` that contain `0`?

Comment: I have updated question at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting requirements property to undefined, then saving it and finally setting requirements object to desired object, like:

```
user.requirements = undefined;
user.save(function(err){
    if (err) ...
    user.requirements = {
        animals = {
            fox: 1
        };
    };
    user.save();
});
```